# How to change input type Number to Text of EditText in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I have a requirement in my project,that by default the input type of the Edittext is Number.How we can give an option to the User to change the input type Number to Text/Alphabets.

Thanks 
Tiru

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a toggle button to switch between number to text and vice versa.

> ***in your layout xml:***

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="InputType"
    android:textOff="Text"
    android:textOn="Number" />
```

> ***Activity class:***

```
EditText ed;
ToggleButton edtb;

//flag : used in the added code

static boolean flag = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edtb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

    edtb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked)
            {
                ed.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            }
            else
            {
                ed.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            }

        }
    });

  /* **Edited** Adding a way to achieve the same using EditText only. */

  ed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(flag)
            {
                ed.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                flag=false;
            }
            else
            {
                ed.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                flag=true;
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I want by using only Editext control, how we can change the soft keyboard input type number to alphabets

Comment: just a note: I feel using a toggle button increases user Experience as the user will have some visual telling him that he could change the setting. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number|text"

         />
```

Answer (score 0):

ToggleButton can help you. Create listener and asociate number type with one state and text with other, when user click the button, the input text will change.

Comment: I want only by using only Editext, how we can change the soft keyboard  input type number to alphabets

Answer (score 0):

First put in xml :

`android:inputType="number"`

change the input type Number to Text/Alphabets dynamically like.

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

Comment: I tried this way,but by default it is showing text, I need to show number by default.User can change it to Text type

Comment: Have you put android:inputType="number" in xml ?

Comment: if you provide  android:inputType="number" in xml then by default it only accept number not all.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve my requirement

Comment: you can use android:inputType="number"
                android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"

Answer (score 0):

if you want only number in EditText
you can use -    android:inputType="number"
                android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"

also use android:numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You can use android:inputType=text and write your own validation code to accept number/single decimal after number etc.